proxy:error [pid 8118] (32)Broken pipe: [client *.*.*.230:50314] AH01084: pass request body failed to [::1]:5100 (localhost) - Nodejs API
I have created an API in nodejs (nestjs framework). Now client API call reaches load balancer then LB distributes the traffic to 2 machines on which nodejs API runs but request first comes to apache web server then using proxy the same request redirects to our node API. This API calls happen full day as its transactional traffic.
Now what I see, there are 502 error intermittent comes everyday in apache access log and below error in apache log.
access log error - *.*.*.230 - - 2024-06-01T20:49:30+0530 "POST /api/v1/email/send/api HTTP/1.1" status=502 msc=136802 "-" "okhttp/4.9.0" *.*.*.84, *.*.*.*
apache error log -
[Sun Jun 02 09:42:06.847067 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 8118] (32)Broken pipe: [client *.*.*.230:50314] AH01084: pass request body failed to [::1]:5100 (localhost)
[Sun Jun 02 09:42:06.847161 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 8118] [client *.*.*.230:50314] AH01097: pass request body failed to [::1]:5100 (localhost) from *.*.*.230 ()

I am sharing the complete confugrations
both server specs  - 8 core, 16GB RAM
nodejs API running with pm2 (10 cluster) on each server
proxy setting in apache -
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName abc.domain.com
        ServerAlias abc.domain.com
        ServerAdmin devops@domain.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/staging/node_processor/current"
        <Directory "/var/www/staging/node_processor">
                AllowOverride all
           RewriteEngine on
           RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
           RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
        </Directory>
        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:5100/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5100/
        LogFormat "%h - %v %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" comonvhost
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/processor_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/processor_access.log  comonvhost
</VirtualHost>

I don't understand this is something because of apache setting or some thread blocking in node service but I see no load on the server. Although On my local system I am not able to reproduce with similar configs and setting.
